# Combinatorics solution

Tags: combinatorics

**Question**

Let $S_n$ be a set of permutations of the set $ \{\ 1, \dots ,n \}\ $.

Call a permutation *good* if the odd integers appear in the odd positions in the permutation and the even integers appear in the even positions.

For example, the permutation 1432 is *good*.

Determine the number of *good* permutations in $S_n$.

**My solution**

Notice that for the first position we have an odd number. We can therefore choose $ \lceil \frac{n}{2} \rceil $ numbers for this position. The next position is an even number and we can therefore choose $ \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor $ numbers for this position.

We end up with a pattern: $ \lceil \frac{n}{2} \rceil \cdot \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor \cdot \lceil \frac{n}{2} \rceil -1 \cdot \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor -1 \dots1  = $ $$ \lceil \frac{n}{2} \rceil ! \cdot \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor !$$

What do you think?

Comment: Yes.  It's the count of arrangements of the odd numbers in the odd positions times the count of arrangements of the even numbers in the even positions.

Comment: The formula is fine. I would prefer $k!k!$ if $n=2k$ and $(k+1)!k!$ if $n=2k+1$.